# mongodb: update nested field, which is given by two variables

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, meteor

I need to set a field `content` to the point element given by the id.

```
{
    "_id" : "kuwBhxAwEsJxc6oXc",
    "points" : [
        {
            "id" : "xdB8TbFweTbc9fecg",
            "pos" : [
                604,
                169
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "uLoorpzQWm49KZ4w3",
            "pos" : [
                197,
                176
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So I got `docId = kuwBhxAwEsJxc6oXc`, `pointId = uLoorpzQWm49KZ4w3` and `content = 'anything'`. 
I tried this:

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: docId, 'points.id': pointId }, 
    { $set: { content: content } }
);
```

The result should be:

```
{
    "_id" : "kuwBhxAwEsJxc6oXc",
    "points" : [
        {
            "id" : "xdB8TbFweTbc9fecg",
            "pos" : [
                604,
                169
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "uLoorpzQWm49KZ4w3",
            "pos" : [
                197,
                176
            ],
            "content": "anything"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [$ operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) in your update like this:

```
Collection.update(
  {_id: docId, 'points.id': pointId},
  {$set: {'points.$.content': content}}
);
```

Comment: Just for understanding: If I want to remove one complete set (id, pos and content), I have to do `{$unset: {'points.$': '' }}`?

Comment: You'd use `$pull` like this: `Collection.update({_id: docId}, {$pull: {points: {id: pointId}}});`

Comment: I understand. Thank you.